# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.view ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:331)

Tags: android

I am new on Android development. I want to develop video player app where list of songs can play. I am getting error like below
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:331)
 at android.view.View.. Please Help me to solve out this.

Below is my main code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mediaplayerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.mediaplayerdemo.R;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;




@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    VideoView mv = new VideoView(getBaseContext());
    public TextView songTitleLabel,startTimeField,endTimeField;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private double startTime = 0;
    private double finalTime = 0;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private ImageButton playButton,stopButton;
    public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private Utilities utils;
    ImageView imgFavorite;
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        reset();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mv.setOnCompletionListener(this); 
        startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        stopButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important

        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        mv.setEnabled(true);

        /*Start Camera*/
        imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              open();
           }
        });
        /*End Camera*/

        playSong(0);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddingMusicActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100);
            }

        });

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //reset();

                if(mv.isPlaying()){

                        if(mv!=null){
                            VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                            mVideoView.pause();
                            //mp.pause();
                            finalTime = mVideoView.getDuration();
                            startTime = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
                            playButton.setEnabled(true);
                            stopButton.setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
                else{
                    if(mv!=null){
                        finalTime = mv.getDuration();
                        startTime = mv.getCurrentPosition();
                        //VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                        //String uriPath1 = "/mnt/sdcard/songsList";
                        //Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(uriPath1);
                        //mVideoView.setVideoPath(uriPath1);
                        //mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri1);
                        //mVideoView.requestFocus();
                        //mVideoView.start();
                        //mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        playButton.setEnabled(false);
                        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                }

                    seekbar.setClickable(true);
                    seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
                    myHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask,100);
                 }

        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                     VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                     mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                     playButton.setEnabled(true);
                     mVideoView.setEnabled(false);
                  }});    
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
             currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");

        }

    }

    private void playSong(int songIndex) {
        try {
            mv.refreshDrawableState();
            mv.setVideoPath(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mv.setOnPreparedListener(null);
            mv.start();
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
            seekbar.setProgress(0);
            seekbar.setMax(100);
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    } 
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mv.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mv.getCurrentPosition();
            startTimeField.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            endTimeField.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
            int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            seekbar.setProgress(progress);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
     }; 

    private void reset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void open(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     mv.suspend();
     }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

My LogCat Details:

```
10-10 16:53:40.490: D/AndroidRuntime(8225): Shutting down VM
10-10 16:53:40.490: W/dalvikvm(8225): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mediaplayerdemo/com.example.mediaplayerdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:331)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2698)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:176)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.widget.VideoView.<init>(VideoView.java:91)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at com.example.mediaplayerdemo.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:39)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
10-10 16:53:40.510: E/AndroidRuntime(8225):     ... 11 more
10-10 16:53:40.840: I/dalvikvm(8225): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 16:53:40.860: I/dalvikvm(8225): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 16:53:41.111: I/dalvikvm(8225): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-10 16:53:41.130: I/dalvikvm(8225): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-10 16:58:40.581: I/Process(8225): Sending signal. PID: 8225 SIG: 9
```

Kindly help me here.

Comment: Your `mv` object created twice. So just replace this  `VideoView mv = new VideoView(getBaseContext());` by  `VideoView mv;`

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating `VideoView` before `onCreate()`, replace

`VideoView mv = new VideoView(getBaseContext());` with `VideoView mv;`

Comment: What you having at line number 174

Comment: "songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);" in the playSong(int songIndex) function.

Comment: check `R.id.songTitle` coming within `activity_main` layout

Answer (score 0):

its problem with

```
 VideoView mv = new VideoView(getBaseContext());
```

change it to.

```
 VideoView mv;
```

(you are initilzed that variable in onCreate() Method.)

Comment: I have done the required changes but now I am getting same error(java.lang.NullPointerException) on different location (at com.example.mediaplayerdemo.MainActivity.playSong(MainActivity.java:174) I have posted the new logcat.  
at com.example.mediaplayerdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)).

Comment: please comment 174 th line